# What does "testing.T" mean in Golang?

Tags: go, testing, interpreter

I'm currently going through *Writing an Interpreter in Go* when I came across this line in the testing unit for the lexer:

```golang
package lexer 

import ( 

"testing"

"monkey/token"

)

func TestNextToken(t *testing.T) {
}
```

What is the purpose of "t *testing.T"? I understand that its a pointer to some field in the testing library, but I'm not sure what it's doing.

Later in the code it's used this way:

```golang
for i, tt := range tests { 
     tok := l.NextToken()

     if tok.Type != tt.expectedType { 
          t.Fatalf("tests[%d] - tokentype wrong. expected=%q, got=%q", i, tt.expectedType, tok.Type) 
     }

     if tok.Literal != tt.expectedLiteral { 
           t.Fatalf("tests[%d] - literal wrong. expected=%q, got=%q", i, tt.expectedLiteral, tok.Literal) 
     }
}
```

I read through the [Golang testing docs](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T), but couldn't really understand what the purpose of it was or why it's being passed to the testing function. All it mentions is that it is a "type passed to Test functions to manage test state and support formatted test logs," though I'm not sure how to interpret that in the context of the above code.

Comment: The Go compiler uses the methods from `t *testing.T` to determine the result of your test. In other languages you may have to write an assertion such as `expect(true).toBe(true)`, whereas in Go, unless you use a third-party package, you just use regular `if` statements to assert something, and then call the methods from `t` to tell the compiler whether what you are testing has passed or has failed.

Comment: `T` is a poorly named type in the `testing` package, an instance of which serves as the interface to the test runtime. You mainly use it to inform the runtime of test failure through calls of `t.Error()` and such, which in turn then affects the exit status of the invocation of the `go test` command which started your test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`func TestNextToken(t *testing.T)` says the function takes a pointer to the [the type T in the testing package](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T). T for tests, F for fuzzing, B for benchmarking, etc. That reference is in the variable `t`.

`testing.T` stores the state of the test. When Go calls your test functions, it passes in the same `testing.T` to each function (presumably). You call methods on it like `t.Fail` to say the test failed, or `t.Skip` to say the test was skipped, etc. It remembers all this, and Go uses it to report what happened in all the test functions.